# Multimonitorsetup: Move starter to bottom on single monitor

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, lts

I'm running a triple monitor setup and with the left monitor in portrait orientation. [Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEK5Z.png)
I'd like to move the starter bar to the bottom only on the left monitor and keep it on the left on the other monitors

OS: Ubuntu LTS 16.04

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Better image [Setup updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEK5Z.png), clarified question

Comment: so correct me if i get this wrong, you just want to have the start bar in one monitor that is on the left, correct? and the image is super tiny a larger one would be more helpful

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the updated setup image I might know how to do what you want, atleast I am sure of one of the two

super edit: well i read it a bit wrong so the answer is wrong and sadly enough i don't think it is possible what you are asking